# Is it possible to store @IndexedEmbedded fields in parent/root with Hibernate Search?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I am looking for a way to index an embedded objects fields on the root/parent level. So if I have a news article with tags, and that news article contains a picture with tags, I'd like the pictures tags to be index on the top level so I don't have to specify a path into the picture when searching. So when indexing an object like the following…

```
{
  title: "my news article",
  tags: ["tag1", "tag2"],
  picture: {
    url: "http://domain.com/path/to/image.jpg",
    tags: ["tag2", "tag3"]
  }
}
```

I'd like to just specify to search only the "tags" field off of my article index and still get a result when searching for the term "tag3".

Something similar to how elastic search can move a nested objects fields to the parent/root with "include_in_parent" and "include_in_parent". [Nested Type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to accomplish this by annotation config.

But you can use a custom [FieldBridge](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/api/org/hibernate/search/bridge/FieldBridge.html) for the `picture` field. Inside your implementation of the `FieldBridge`, you will handle the special use case and add the `picture.tags` elements to the `tags` field of the index document.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for an easier way I was missing, but it certainly is doable that way!